# SQL ORACLE 12C ERROR: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following

Tags: sql, oracle, compiler-errors

I checked on some SQL validation sites and they found that this script works and that it was correct, but when I make a query in database, it returns me some errors that I will show below. What should I do?

My database: Oracle version 12c. I use SqlDbx.

The script:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SPE210EST()
IS
  v_QtdDis LONG;
  v_TraDep LONG;
  v_QtdFat LONG;
  v_QtdDev LONG;
  v_QtdOrd LONG;
  v_QtdEst LONG;
  v_QtdBlo LONG;
  v_QtdRae LONG;
  v_QtdRes LONG;
  v_CodEmp NUMBER;
  v_CodPro VARCHAR(14);
  v_CodDer VARCHAR(7);
  v_CodDep VARCHAR(10);
BEGIN
 SELECT E210EST.CodEmp INTO v_CodEmp, E210EST.CodPro INTO v_CodPro, E210EST.CodDer INTO v_CodDer, E210EST.CodDep INTO v_CodDep, E210EST.QtdEst INTO v_QtdEst, E210EST.QtdBlo INTO v_QtdBlo, E210EST.QtdRae INTO v_QtdRae, E210EST.QtdRes INTO v_QtdRes, E210EST.QtdOrd INTO v_QtdOrd
   FROM E210EST, E075PRO 
  WHERE E210EST.CodEmp = E075PRO.CodEmp 
    AND E210EST.CodPro = E075PRO.CodPro
    AND E210EST.CodDep IN ('1','3','4','5','9')
    AND (CASE WHEN (E210EST.QtdEst - E210EST.QtdBlo - E210EST.QtdRae - E210EST.QtdRes) < 0 THEN 0 ELSE E210EST.QtdEst - E210EST.QtdBlo - E210EST.QtdRae - E210EST.QtdRes END) <> (CASE WHEN E210EST.CodDep = '1' THEN E075PRO.USU_Dep1 WHEN E210EST.CodDep = '3' THEN E075PRO.USU_Dep3 WHEN E210EST.CodDep = '4' THEN E075PRO.USU_Dep4 WHEN E210EST.CodDep = '5' THEN E075PRO.USU_Dep5 WHEN E210EST.CodDep = '9' THEN E075PRO.USU_Dep9 END);
 
 v_QtdDis := (:v_QtdEst - :v_QtdBlo - :v_QtdRae - :v_QtdRes);
 v_QtdOrd := :v_QtdOrd;
 v_QtdFat := 0;
 v_TraDep := 0;
 v_QtdDev := 0;
 
 IF (:v_CodDep = '1' OR  :v_CodDep = '3' OR :v_CodDep = '4' OR :v_CodDep = '5' OR :v_CodDep = '9') THEN
  SELECT CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(UPPER(E000IPC.UNINFC),'Ç','C'),' ',''),'UND','UN'),'PT','UN'),'M','MT'),'RL','UN') <> E075PRO.UNIMED
                            THEN (SELECT CASE WHEN E015TCU.TIPCNV = '*' THEN E000IPC.QTDREC * E015TCU.VLRCNV 
                                              WHEN E015TCU.TIPCNV = '/' THEN E000IPC.QTDREC / E015TCU.VLRCNV END 
                                    FROM E015TCU 
                                   WHERE E015TCU.UNIMED = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(UPPER(E000IPC.UNINFC),'Ç','C'),' ',''),'UND','UN'),'PT','UN'),'M','MT'),'RL','UN') 
                                     AND E015TCU.UNIME2 = E075PRO.UNIMED)
                       ELSE E000IPC.QTDREC END) IS NULL THEN 0
              ELSE SUM(CASE WHEN REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(UPPER(E000IPC.UNINFC),'Ç','C'),' ',''),'UND','UN'),'PT','UN'),'M','MT'),'RL','UN') <> E075PRO.UNIMED
                            THEN (SELECT CASE WHEN E015TCU.TIPCNV = '*' THEN E000IPC.QTDREC * E015TCU.VLRCNV 
                                              WHEN E015TCU.TIPCNV = '/' THEN E000IPC.QTDREC / E015TCU.VLRCNV END 
                                    FROM E015TCU 
                                   WHERE E015TCU.UNIMED = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(UPPER(E000IPC.UNINFC),'Ç','C'),' ',''),'UND','UN'),'PT','UN'),'M','MT'),'RL','UN') 
                                     AND E015TCU.UNIME2 = E075PRO.UNIMED)
                       ELSE E000IPC.QTDREC END)
               END INTO v_TraDep
    FROM E000NFC,E000IPC,E070FIL,E095FOR,E403FPR,E075PRO                 
   WHERE E000NFC.SITNFC = '1'                                     
     AND E000NFC.TIPNFE = 1                                       
     AND E000NFC.STANFV <> 3                                      
     AND E000NFC.INDCAN <> 'S'                                    
     AND E000NFC.CGCFIL = E000IPC.CGCFIL                          
     AND E000NFC.CGCFOR = E000IPC.CGCFOR                          
     AND E000NFC.CHVNEL = E000IPC.CHVNEL                          
     AND E403FPR.CODEMP = E075PRO.CODEMP
     AND E403FPR.CODPRO = E075PRO.CODPRO
     AND E403FPR.CODEMP = :v_CodEmp
     AND E403FPR.CODPRO = :v_CodPro
     AND E403FPR.CODDER = :v_CodDer
     AND E000IPC.CODDEP = :v_CodDep
     AND E000IPC.CODDEP IN ('1','3','4','5','9')
     AND E000IPC.NOPPRO IN ('5101','5102','5401','5402','5403','5405','6101','6102','6401','6402','6403','6404')
     AND E070FIL.NUMCGC = E000NFC.CGCFIL                          
     AND E095FOR.CGCCPF = E000NFC.CGCFOR                          
     AND E403FPR.CODEMP = E070FIL.CODEMP                          
     AND E403FPR.CODFOR = E095FOR.CODFOR                          
     AND E403FPR.PROFOR = E000IPC.PROFOR;

  SELECT CASE WHEN SUM(E140IPV.QTDFAT) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE SUM(E140IPV.QTDFAT) END INTO V_QtdFat
    FROM E140NFV, E140IPV, E090REP, E001TNS, E120PED
   WHERE E140NFV.CODEMP = E140IPV.CODEMP                           
     AND E140NFV.CODFIL = E140IPV.CODFIL                          
     AND E140NFV.CODSNF = E140IPV.CODSNF                          
     AND E140NFV.NUMNFV = E140IPV.NUMNFV                          
     AND E140NFV.CODREP = E090REP.CODREP                          
     AND E120PED.CODEMP = E140IPV.CODEMP                          
     AND E120PED.CODFIL = E140IPV.FILPED                          
     AND E120PED.NUMPED = E140IPV.NUMPED                          
     AND E120PED.USU_PEDPRJ <> 'P'                                
     AND E140NFV.CODSNF = 'NFE'                                   
     AND E140NFV.CODFIL IN (1,3,4,5,9)                                 
     AND E140NFV.DATEMI >= (SYSDATE-91)                             
     AND E140NFV.DATEMI < (SYSDATE)                              
     AND E140NFV.SITNFV = '2'                                     
     AND E140NFV.TIPNFS IN (1,10)                                 
     AND E140IPV.CODPRO = :v_CodPro
     AND E140IPV.CODDER = :v_CodDer
     AND E140IPV.CODDEP IN ('1','3','4','5','9')
     AND E090REP.USU_GrpRep = TO_NUMBER(:v_CodDep)
     AND E140IPV.CODEMP = E001TNS.CODEMP                          
     AND E140IPV.TNSPRO = E001TNS.CODTNS                          
     AND E001TNS.VENFAT = 'S'                                     
     AND E140IPV.CODEMP = :v_CodEmp;

  SELECT CASE WHEN SUM(E440IPC.QTDEST) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE SUM(E440IPC.QTDEST) END INTO v_QtdDev 
    FROM E440NFC,E075PRO,E440IPC,E001TNS,E090REP                      
   WHERE E440NFC.CODEMP = :v_CodEmp
     AND E440NFC.CODFIL IN (1,3,4,5,9)                                
     AND E440NFC.DATENT >= (SYSDATE-91)
     AND E440NFC.DATENT < (SYSDATE)
     AND E440IPC.CODEMP = E440NFC.CODEMP                              
     AND E440IPC.CODFIL = E440NFC.CODFIL                              
     AND E440IPC.CODFOR = E440NFC.CODFOR                              
     AND E440IPC.NUMNFC = E440NFC.NUMNFC                              
     AND E440IPC.CODSNF = E440NFC.CODSNF                              
     AND E440IPC.CODEMP = E075PRO.CODEMP                              
     AND E440IPC.CODPRO = E075PRO.CODPRO 
     AND E440IPC.CODDEP IN ('1','3','4','5','9')   
     AND E075PRO.CODPRO = :v_CodPro
     AND E440IPC.CODDER = :v_CodDer
     AND E090REP.USU_GRPREP = TO_NUMBER(:v_CodDep)
     AND (E440NFC.TIPNFE = 3 OR E440NFC.TIPNFE = 2)                   
     AND E440NFC.SITNFC = '2'                                         
     AND E440IPC.CODEMP = E001TNS.CODEMP                              
     AND E440IPC.TNSPRO = E001TNS.CODTNS                              
     AND E440NFC.USU_CODREP = E090REP.CODREP                          
     AND E001TNS.CPRTCF = 'D';

  IF (v_QtdDis < 0) THEN
    v_QtdDis := 0;
  END IF;

  IF (:v_CodDep = '1') THEN
   UPDATE E075PRO 
      SET USU_DEP1 = v_QtdDis,
          USU_TRADP1 = v_TraDep, 
          USU_MINCCO = ((V_QtdFat - v_QtdDev)/90) * 20
    WHERE CODEMP = :v_CodEmp 
      AND CODPRO = :v_CodPro; 
  END IF;
  IF (:v_CodDep = '3') THEN
   UPDATE E075PRO 
      SET USU_DEP3 = v_QtdDis,
          USU_TRADP3 = v_TraDep, 
          USU_MINJOI = ((V_QtdFat - v_QtdDev)/90) * 20
    WHERE CODEMP = :v_CodEmp 
      AND CODPRO = :v_CodPro; 
  END IF;
  IF (:v_CodDep = '4') THEN
   UPDATE E075PRO 
      SET USU_DEP4 = v_QtdDis,
          USU_TRADP4 = v_TraDep, 
          USU_MINSJ = ((V_QtdFat - v_QtdDev)/90) * 20
    WHERE CODEMP = :v_CodEmp 
      AND CODPRO = :v_CodPro; 
  END IF;
  IF (:v_CodDep = '5') THEN
   UPDATE E075PRO 
      SET USU_DEP5 = v_QtdDis,
          USU_TRADP5 = v_TraDep, 
          USU_MINJDS = ((V_QtdFat - v_QtdDev)/90) * 20
    WHERE CODEMP = :v_CodEmp 
      AND CODPRO = :v_CodPro; 
  END IF;
  IF (:v_CodDep = '9') THEN
   UPDATE E075PRO 
      SET USU_DEP9 = v_QtdDis,
          USU_TRADP9 = v_TraDep, 
          USU_MINFLN = ((V_QtdFat - v_QtdDev)/90) * 20
    WHERE CODEMP = :v_CodEmp 
      AND CODPRO = :v_CodPro; 
  END IF;
 END IF;
END SPE210EST
```

The error it returns:

```
1   ORA-24344: success with compilation error
1   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:
1    <an identifier>
1    <an identifier delimited by double quotes> current delete
1    there is prior   
1      
17  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INTO" when expecting one of the following:
17  
17     . ( , % de
17  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INTO" when expecting one of the following:
17  
17     . ( , % ; limite
17  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INTO" when expecting one of the following:
17  
17     . ( , % ; limite
17  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INTO" when expecting one of the following:
17  
17     . ( , % ; limite
17  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INTO" when expecting one of the following:
17  
17     . ( , % ; limite
17  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INTO" when expecting one of the following:
17  
17     . ( , % ; limite
17  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INTO" when expecting one of the following:
17  
17     . ( , % ; limite
17  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INTO" when expecting one of the following:
17  
17     . ( , % ; limite
```

Comment: Did you try breaking it down section by section? I mean, commenting out the body of the script to ensure it compiles, then doing the script with the first query, then the first and second, and so forth. (I see there is already an answer here, but I do recommend this in general. You likely would have realized that your `create procedure` syntax was wrong and could have asked a very specific question without a wall of text).

Comment: "I checked on some SQL validation sites and they found that this script works and that it was correct," Then it would suggest that the SQL validation sites are not valid.

Comment: LONG is a (deprecated) character type; it looks like you're trying to use it as a number - so should use NUMBER.

Comment: @EdmCoff -- the error message says line 1 -- don't have to look far to know where the error is.

Comment: @Hogan Fair enough. You're right and I didn't really think about that. I was just trying to provide some general advice for breaking down the problem. If OP realized the problem was in the create syntax, they could have provided a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @EdmCoff -- Yes, your advice was a very good tip.  It goes hand in hand with - understand error messages completely if possible (often error messages are bad and not helpful -- but many times the answer will be right there.)

Comment: Please, **minimize** the code before asking a question. Should we debug it for you?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_name
IS
  v_a VARCHAR2(20);
  v_b VARCHAR2(20);
  v_c VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
  SELECT dummy, dummy, dummy
  INTO   v_a, v_b, v_c
  FROM   DUAL;
END;
/
```

You do not need the `()` braces after the procedure name if there are no parameters and it is `SELECT <list of columns> INTO <list of variables> FROM ...`.

Comment: This can be seen on the documentation page at https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_procedure.htm#GUID-5F84DB47-B5BE-4292-848F-756BF365EC54__BABJEGID